# How to create a marker only drawable into the bounds of the circle area?

Tags: android, location, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I need show a marker only into the bounds of a drawn circle whose area is the precision of the location. The draw of the circle is no problem but the limits of the draggable area is no possible for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to improve your question by explaning what you want to achieve and maybe adding some screenshots / images.

Comment: My proposal is similar to this example:

http://unserkaiser.com/code/google-maps-marker-check-if-in-circle/

 If the condition returns true the marker will be dragable. The intention is the marker no leaves outside the bounds of a circle.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot limit draggable area using API.

Your options are:

1. saving `Marker` position when drag starts, checking when it ends and reverting if it is outside
2. same above but checking in all drag callbacks, however this looks weird if you try `setPosition` in `onDrag` (notice marker blinks sometimes where it would be if you didn't `setPosition`)
3. posting a feature request on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype=Android2)

Comment: Also works for me if the markers be drawable in onMapClick only on this area. This is possible?